# How to sort divs according to color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

What I need: I am developing a website using HTML, CSS, Javascript/JQuery. I have 6 divs. Based on conditions divs have to change their color,size, text and divs have to sort according to colors(red, orange and then green).

What I implemented: I have created three classes in CSS reddivs, orangedivs, and greendivs. Now the divs are changing their colors but they are not sorting according to colors. I tried to prepend them, then  it's not according to expectations.

What I am struggling: I am unable to sort the divs according to colors. Any ideas are welcome! Below are supplements

```js
createDiv_111(5100);

function createDiv_111(num) {

  if (num >= 5000 && num <= 5300) {

    var resize_to_red = document.getElementById('box0');

    resize_to_red.classList.add("reddivs");
    resize_to_red.innerHTML = "ERROR";

    $("#divs_container").prepend(document.getElementById('yellow_reach_limit_box'));
  } else if (num >= 20 && num <= 30) {

    var resize_to_orange = document.getElementById('box0');

    resize_to_orange.classList.add("orangedivs");
    resize_to_orange.innerHTML = "changed to orange";
    $("#divs_container").prepend(document.getElementById('yellow_reach_limit_box'));
  } else if (num >= 30 && num <= 40) {

    var resize_to_green = document.getElementById('box0');


    resize_to_green.classList.add("greendivs");
    resize_to_green.innerHTML = "changed to green";

  }
}
```

```css
.reddivs {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  width: 590px;
  height: 155px;
  background: #BE0A26;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 25px 10px 23px;
}

.orangedivs {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  line-height: 26px;
  width: 151px;
  height: 109.5px;
  background: #E86B0B;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 26px 10px 23px;
}

.greendivs {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #00A096;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 40px 30px 20px 24px;
}

.container_for_alldivs {
  width: 660px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container_for_alldivs" id="divs_container">
  <div id="box0" class="alldivs"></div>
  <div id="box1" class="alldivs"></div>
  <div id="box2" class="alldivs"></div>
  <div id="box3" class="alldivs"></div>
  <div id="box4" class="alldivs"></div>
  <div id="box5" class="alldivs"></div>
</div>
```

I am posting code for box0 div, but condition for remaining divs are same except the id changes to box1 or box2,...,box5

Comment: when you do document.getElementById('box1') and turn it into a variable, you can access the style attributes of the variable and then go from there. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp do a conditional statement to compare. Also  you have (num >= 30 && num <= 40) and (num >= 20 && num <= 30) happening at the same time. they could both be true at 30, which could mess stuff up

Comment: Looking at your code, the prepend statement is prepending an element called "yellow_reach_limit_box". What's that? Aren't you trying to prepend "resize_to_xxxx"?. Also, I'd just have three divs within the container div (one for each colour), then add the new box into its respective div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to sort by `css` class names (which i find a bit of a hack) You can grab all elements and sort them by their `className` attribute.

Simple example:

```js
$('#sort').on('click', function() {
  var sortedElements = $('.greendivs, .orangedivs, .reddivs').sort(function(a, b) {
    debugger
    return a.className > b.className;
  });

  $('.container_for_alldivs').html(sortedElements);
});
```

```css
.reddivs {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  width: 590px;
  height: 155px;
  background: #BE0A26;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 25px 10px 23px;
}

.orangedivs {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  line-height: 26px;
  width: 151px;
  height: 109.5px;
  background: #E86B0B;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 26px 10px 23px;
}

.greendivs {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #00A096;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 40px 30px 20px 24px;
}

.container_for_alldivs {
  width: 660px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sort">Sort</button>
<div class="container_for_alldivs" id="divs_container">

  <div id="box0" class="alldivs">

  </div>


  <div id="box1" class="alldivs greendivs">

  </div>


  <div id="box2" class="alldivs orangedivs">

  </div>


  <div id="box3" class="alldivs reddivs">

  </div>


  <div id="box4" class="alldivs greendivs">

  </div>


  <div id="box5" class="alldivs reddivs">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This solution is working. How can I automate the function? so that divs have to sort automatically

Answer (score 1):

[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is widely supported and you can also use it to reorder divs with css only:

Just add the following to your container:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
```

And add the order for the div, like this:

```
order: 3;
```

I also updated your script to loop through all boxes and take a random number from an array to test this.

Green divs are always first, then orange second and finally red third. Update the css to specify the ordering you require.

---

### Example

```js
//options array
var options = [25, 35, 5250];

$(".alldivs").each(function(i, box)
{
  //get random number from array
  var number = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];
  createDiv_111(number, box);
});


function createDiv_111(num, box) 
{
  if (num >= 5000 && num <= 5300) 
  {
    var resize_to_red = box;
    resize_to_red.classList.add("reddivs");
    resize_to_red.innerHTML = "ERROR";
  } 
  else if (num >= 20 && num <= 30) 
  {
    var resize_to_orange = box;
    resize_to_orange.classList.add("orangedivs");
    resize_to_orange.innerHTML = "changed to orange";
  } 
  else if (num >= 30 && num <= 40) 
  {
    var resize_to_green = box;
    resize_to_green.classList.add("greendivs");
    resize_to_green.innerHTML = "changed to green";
  }
}
```

```css
.reddivs, .orangedivs,.greendivs {
  /* No need to repeat these */
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

.reddivs {
  top: 15px;
  width: 590px;
  height: 155px;
  background: #BE0A26;
  margin: 10px 25px 10px 23px;
  order: 3;
}

.orangedivs {
  top: 30px;
  line-height: 26px;
  width: 151px;
  height: 109.5px;
  background: #E86B0B;
  margin: 10px 26px 10px 23px;
  order: 2;
}

.greendivs {
  top: 35px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #00A096;
  margin: 40px 30px 20px 24px;
  order: 1;
}

.container_for_alldivs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 660px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container_for_alldivs" id="divs_container">
  <div id="box0" class="alldivs"></div>
  <div id="box1" class="alldivs"></div>
  <div id="box2" class="alldivs"></div>
  <div id="box3" class="alldivs"></div>
  <div id="box4" class="alldivs"></div>
  <div id="box5" class="alldivs"></div>
</div>
```

p.s. I also tidied up your css to recycle any styles reused between colored divs.

Comment: I have three divs in a row. This is working but divs are not arrangng one by one. any more suggestions please.

Comment: @SarabuSandeep Check my updated answer. Should solve your problem now. Green divs are always first, then orange second and finally red third. Update the css to specify the ordering you require.

Comment: @SarabuSandeep Update the flex-direction to use row instead of column. Snippet updated.